# I keep on getting this error TypeError: Invalid path type: module each time i try to run my html files on the django server. i've been stuck forever

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

[image: problem log][image]
Please i can provide more screenshots if needed. I've meet with my lecturer and he doesn't seem to know why the are errors on the code and why its not running properly.

Tried including the templates to templates directory in settings.py I've tried creating an entirely different project to see where i made my mistake still can't find it

Comment: Could you please provide the error log ?

Comment: I have please click on problem log sir

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename your directory name to "templates" (in lowercase and with an s at the end) instead of "Template". By default Django template engine will try to load templates from the [templates subdirectory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something:%7E:text=First%2C%20create%20a%20directory%20called%20templates%20in%20your%20polls%20directory.%20Django%20will%20look%20for%20templates%20in%20there.) inside each installed application.

Also, the [template's application directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something:%7E:text=Within%20the%20templates%20directory%20you%20have%20just%20created%2C%20create%20another%20directory%20called%20polls%2C) name should be the same as your application. For example : "psychology_app/templates/psychology_app/"

Here's some Django Django documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TEMPLATES
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something